# Modal backdrop - how to remove background color

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire

After adding livewire to my laravel project, every drawer / modal popup window creates a background, that hides everything under the pop-up window. I have managed to get rid of the drawer background, but soon realized i need it to be able to close the side menu, so i just need to change the color.

My question is where should I change the bg color? Is there a setting file? Or should i add some class to the modal / drawer?

This is the element that appers on opening the modal

```
<div modal-backdrop="" class="bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50 dark:bg-opacity-80 fixed inset-0 z-40"></div>
```

The blade file

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<button class="btn" data-modal-target="crud-modal" data-modal-toggle="crud-modal" type="button">
        ...
    </button>
    <div class="fixed left-0 right-0 top-0 z-50 hidden h-screen items-center justify-center bg-transparent" id="crud-modal"
         aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="relative w-6/12 rounded-lg bg-gray-700 p-10 text-white shadow">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between rounded-t border-b dark:border-zinc-800 md:p-5">
                <button class="btn" data-modal-toggle="crud-modal" type="button">
                    ...
                </button>
            </div>
            <form class="space-y-4" method="POST" action="{{ route('warehouse') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                ...
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

I tried removing the modal window with every variation of data-modal-backdrop="false", that i could find but none of them worked. I tried to find how to style it, but since it doesnt have id i dont know how to access it..

Comment: Change the classes `bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50 dark:bg-opacity-80` to what you want your backdrop to look like. There's a [list of available colors](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors).

Comment: Thanks for help! That's clever to address all of them at once. I have literally been stuck on this for about last two hours..

Answer (score 0):

Change the classes bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50 dark:bg-opacity-80 to what you want your backdrop to look like. There's a list of available colors.

Posted by @brombeer

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you are using Livewire along with Tailwind CSS styling for your Laravel project. The issue you described is related to the background of the modal window, which is created using the element .

To change the color of this background, you need to modify the styles associated with this class. You can either use or add your own styles to your CSS file, or directly add them to the HTML file. In your case, you want to change the background color for the class bg-gray-900, which is background-color: #111827;.

Here's an example of how you can change this color:

```
<style>
    .bg-gray-900 {
        background-color: #your-desired-color;
    }
</style>
```

Add this to your Blade template or include it in one of your CSS files. Replace #your-desired-color with your desired color.

Comment: Oh, AI! Why not simply exchange the class with another class that has the color OP wants? Why change a _named_ color sitewide? Does overwriting the existing style work without an `!important` flag?

Comment: Certainly, you can replace the class with another class that has the desired color. However, changing the named color for the entire site might be considered a bit broad, especially if this color is used in different contexts. The choice between swapping classes and changing the color directly depends on your specific use case and how you've organized your styles.
I'm not saying that your approach is incorrect. No, both your response and mine are correct. It's just a matter of considering maintenance convenience and code clarity. I simply provided an answer to the question in this forum.

Comment: Regarding code clarity: if I apply a class `bg-gray-900` anywhere in my project I'd expect it to be dark gray, not light red or whatever color I set here